# What is the best for WP7: SQLite or Data.Linq?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I'm using SQLite in my App (WP 7.1 and Community.CsharpSqlite.SqlLiteClient.WP7.dll assembly).

The SQLite DataReader object is very slow when I use inner join (about 3 to 5 seconds to populate a list with 1000 records).

I'm thinking to remove the SQLite database and start to use a "sdf" database.

Does anyone know why the SQLite DataReader object is so slow in WP?

Here is my sample code (table1is a table with 5000 records and 5 columns. table2 have chield records from table1)

```
using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(PhoneUtil.ConnectionString))
{
   conn.Open();
   using (SqliteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandText = "select t1.* from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t1.year=2013";

      // the line below is very slow.
      using (SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
         // Here is fast
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            // ...
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables?

Comment: If I run the query directly on database, I get the results very fast. The problem is when I run from the App. And also, the problem occurs only in the ExecuteReader() method.

Comment: ExecuteReader _may_ read the whole result before returning the first result, if the result is big, it may take a while. The SQLite shell (as far as I can remember) returns the first found value immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the SQlite implementation for WP7 is completely managed code is probably at least partially the reason.